# Code different for Depth and Height - Binary Search Tree (Python)

Tags: python

I am confuse, what is the different in code for depth and height in binary search tree?
I did a google to check on the code for depth, as well as the code for height.
It kind of turn out to be the same.

Can someone tell me the differences?
Anyway, below is my code for height as well as depth.
But my depth isn't working.

```
def height(self,key):
    node = self.root
    while node is not None:
        if node.key == key:
            return self.height2(node)
        elif node.key > key:
            node = node.left
        else:
            node = node.right

def height2(self,n):
    if n is None:
        return -1
    else:
        #return the max
        return  1 + max(self.height2(n.left),self.height2(n.right))
```

For the depth

```
def depth(self,node):
    node = self.root
    if node.left == None and node.right == None:
        return 1
    elif node.left == None:
        return node.right.depth() + 1
    elif node.right == None:
        return node.left.depth() + 1
    else:
         return  1 + max(self.depth(node.left),self.depth(node.right))
```

Edited for depth:

```
 def depth(self,key):
        temp = self.root
        while temp is not None:
            if temp.key == key:
                return temp.val
            elif temp.key > key:
                temp = temp.left
            else:
                temp = temp.right
        return return  1 + max(self.depth(node.left),self.depth(node.right))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depth is a value associated to a single node in a tree, it's the number of edges from a node to root node. Root node has a depth of 0. Height on the other hand is the longest path from a node to root, i.e. max depth of any node in the tree.

The code you have seem to work just fine, `height2` is enough to determine the the height of a tree. If you need determine a depth of a node you'd need to first find it.

Assuming the tree is BST then following code would return the depth or -1 if the key is not in the tree:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def depth(root, key, current_depth=0):
    if not root:
        return -1
    elif root.key == key:
        return current_depth
    elif key < root.key:
        return depth(root.left, key, current_depth + 1)
    else:
        return depth(root.right, key, current_depth + 1)

root = Node(3)
root.left = Node(2)
root.left.left = Node(1)

for i in xrange(1, 4):
    print 'key: {0}, depth: {1}'.format(i, depth(root, i))

# key: 1, depth: 2
# key: 2, depth: 1
# key: 3, depth: 0
```

Comment: When you determine the height you can just scan the whole tree without inspecting the values of the nodes. This is exactly what's happening in `height2`. Determining the depth of a node you need to find it first.

Comment: That mean the code that I have for my depth is wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's not checking the values/keys at all.

Comment: In the current form the code won't run and it's returning value of a node, not depth: `return temp.val`

Comment: actually, i can't even run your code, because it stated that needed 3 argument, but 4 is given

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106625/discussion-between-niemmi-and-stack).